# R: How to get an object inside list using get() or mget()?

Tags: r

I have a list `mylist` with named objects in it.

Say one of them is called `a`.

How do I get `a` from outside the list assuming the name of the list is unknown? I want to be able to say `get("a")` and get `my_list$a` back.

But that doesn't work.

Comment: That's not what I mean. I want to specifically use the get or mget-functions here. The idea is that I don't know what the name of the list is, only the name of the element. (I see that my question did not make this clear at all, sorry).

Comment: *"I don't know what the name of the list is"* That doesn't make sense to me. You need to know *where* to look for element `a`, don't you? Your list is probably created as part of some function? Then you know the name of the object. `get` (or `mget`) should not be necessary here.

Comment: Do you want to search through all of the lists in your current scope for an element "a" in one of them?  Are you assuming that there's only one such element? (i.e. @Adam's answer ...)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do something like this (hacked together quickly). I bet there are weird things that can crash this.

Basically I am just using `objects()` to list all of the objects in the environment. Then the function checks each one to see if it is a list. If it is a list, see if it has list element named to that of your search string.

```
a <- 1:5
b <- list(hello = "words", goodbye = 1:4)
c <- lm(mtcars)
d <- list(xyz = 1:100)
x <- list(hello = "dsfsfd", goodbye = 5:16)

check_list <- function(o, search) {

  item <- eval(parse(text = o))

  if (is.list(item)) {
    if (search %in% names(item)) {
      paste(o, "$", search, sep = "")
    } 
  }
}

search <- unlist(lapply(objects()[objects() != "search"], check_list, search = "goodbye"))
```

In this case I am looking for list element "goodbye", which is found in `b` and `x`.

```
> search
[1] "b$goodbye" "x$goodbye"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, maybe this is practical for your case:

```
library(purrr)
# some lists
l1 <- list("A" = 0, "B" = NA)
l2 <- list("C" = 8)
l3 <- list("X" = NULL, "a" = 12)

# combine them in a list
list_of_lists <- list(l1, l2, l3)
which_list <- list_of_lists %>% 
  # use map to search for the name you are looking for
  map("a") %>% 
  # in case you want to get the positions of the lists that contain
  # the desired named element, derive a logical vector
  map_lgl(negate(is.null))

# get the desired list
list_of_lists[which_list]
```